# InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 3 which is outside the valid range of [0, 3) tensorflow sentimen analysis

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis

So i try to learn sentimen analysis with tensorflow,my data set is contain 3 y_labels that is `1 == 'negative,2=='neutral,3=='positive'`. Here is my code

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size,oov_token=oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)

word_index =tokenizer.word_index

training_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
testing_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

training_padding = pad_sequences(training_sequence,maxlen=max_length,padding=padding_type)
test_padding = pad_sequences(training_sequence,maxlen=max_length,padding=padding_type)

training_padded = np.array(training_padding)
training_label = np.array(y_train)

test_padded = np.array(test_padding)
test_label = np.array(y_test)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size,embedding_dim,input_length=max_length ),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(40,activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='relu')

])
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
num_epoch = 200
history = model.fit(training_padded,training_label,epochs=num_epoch)
```

But i got an error,which i cut a little bit since its too long.x

```
invalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 3 which is outside the valid range of [0, 3).  Label values: 2 2 1 3 3 1 1 1 3 2 3 1 3 3 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 3 3 1 3 2 2
     [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits
 (defined at c:\users\pc\pycharmprojects\deeplearning_sentiment_analysis\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py:5113)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3960]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
```

In my perspective what i have done already correct,can anyone tell me what is wrong?.
For my understanding in we can build classification in `sequental()` but all resource it only for binary classification `[0,1]` ,can we build for more than 2 class?

here my example dataframe

[image: dataframe example]

Comment: Your labels should be 0,1,2 instead of 1,2,3.

Comment: Hi already try your suggestion for neg = 0,netral = 1, and pos = 2 and it work but i got confused,when I try predict a sentences with `print(np.rint(model.predict(padded)))` and it give a result of `[[1. 1. 0.]]` . is that sentences neg,pos or net?

Answer (score 0):

I got the anser from Luke Borowy that in multiclass or multi label classification all label should start from 0